# How is "stripping such words as remained of orthodox meanings" meant to be understood grammatically?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, past-participles

I was wondering if someone could help me out with a certain phrase I want to grasp the meaning of. I have two different meanings in my mind, and I was hoping that someone could point out the right one.

> ...stripping such words **as remained of orthodox meanings**...

The context of the phrase is the process of the diminution of the English language by the ruling party, as depicted in the appendix to the novel *1984*, designed to expurgate words of all their undesired meanings, so as to preclude the articulation of subversive thoughts by people.

The full sentence is as follows:

> This was done partly by the invention of new words, but chiefly by eliminating undesirable words and by stripping such words **as remained of orthodox meanings**, and so far as possible of all secondary meanings whatever.

I'm wavering between reading "as remained of orthodox meanings" as

1. "so that they retain only orthodox meanings" (orthodox in party terms) and
2. "that had retained their original, conventional meanings (and are now ought to be revised)".

Which one is it?

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for your question.  [The Ministry of Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Love) "enforces loyalty and love of Big Brother through fear, a repressive apparatus, and brainwashing. The Ministry of Love building has no windows and is surrounded by barbed wire entanglements, steel doors, hidden machine-gun nests, and guards armed with jointed truncheons."  The very name of this ministry serves as an excellent example of *stripping words* of their *orthodox meanings.*

Comment: The quote you have provided relates directly to the Ministry's creation of a new language called [Newspeak,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak) "a controlled language created by the totalitarian state as a tool to limit free thought, and concepts that pose a threat to the regime such as freedom, self-expression, individuality, peace, etc. Any form of thought alternative to the party’s construct is classified as thoughtcrime."

Comment: Change 'such' => 'the', and 'as' => 'that'.  "stripping the words that remained of (their) orthodox meanings..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase 'as remained' does not belong with 'of orthodox meanings', it belongs with 'stripping such words'. It helps to take the sentence apart:

> This was done .... chiefly by eliminating undesirable words...

*This* was achieved by removing unwanted words...

> ...  and by stripping [such words as remained] of orthodox meanings, and so far as possible of all secondary meanings whatever."

ie stripping those [words which were left after you have eliminated the undesirable ones] of their orthodox meanings.

Comment: Put another way, the string "as remained of orthodox meanings" is not a constituent. [such words as remained] is a constituent, and [stripping [such words as remained] of orthodox meanings] is a constituent, but "as remained of orthodox meanings" is not a constituent. Grammatical phenomena only apply to constituents.

Answer (score 2):

I read it as meaning:

> stripping (removing) the orthodox meanings from any words which (still remained) after the undesirable words had been eliminated (removed).